# python pdf to text convert

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to convert pdf into text. I tried this code in python command prompt but it is not showing any output. Maybe I'm wrong. Can you please tell me where im wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
import pyPdf

def getPDFContent(path):
    content = ""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
    # Iterate pages
    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    # Collapse whitespace
    content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
    return content

print getPDFContent("test.pdf").encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

Comment: Pointless code without a related PDF reference causing the problem.

Comment: This code is working with a standard PDF

Answer (score 2):

If your PDF contains only images (e.g. from a scanned page) then you won't be able to extract any text.

Comment: actually my  pdf contain gre word list text no image is there. Dont knw y its not showing any output.

Comment: and as said: provide a reference to the related pdf file

Comment: actually my pdf contain gre word list text no image is there. Dont knw y its not showing any output. i think there might be something wrong in my code.

Comment: @Gur: you are repeating yourself - we **need a sample document** - either you provide it in order to get help or nobody can/will actually help you.

Comment: i jus taken example of any pdf file .(Gre wordlist gre is a exam which is for master degree those student applying for master can apply in any university.)now please let me knw where im wrong in my above code. its not showing any output

Comment: ignore gre jus take any pdf example i want to convert pdf into text as above my code is not working u jus take any pdf file and see my code as above my problem is its not showing any output

Comment: It *is* working for me with any PDF document

Comment: @gur: The code does work on standard PDFs. Please go to somewhere like https://www.rapidshare.com/, upload the PDF file that is giving you problems, and come back here and give us the link. Then we can test it for ourselves.

Comment: i upload my books.pdf now you may check

Comment: @gur: Thats nice. How can we download it? If you want us to check it, you need to give us a link to where we can download it from.